# Using boost property tree to read int array

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I have some JSON with a handful of integer array variables, like so:

```
{"a": [8, 6, 2], "b": [2, 2, 1]}
```

I would like to use boost property_tree, for instance:

```
std::stringstream ss;
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

ss << "{\"a\": [8, 6, 2], \"b\": [2, 2, 1]}";

boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);
std::vector<int> a = pt.get<std::vector<int> >("a");
```

This doesn't work, nor does any variation on an int pointer that I've tried. How may I read an array from a property tree?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with boost property tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972252/parsing-json-with-boost-property-tree)

Comment: The answer to that question does not cover the specific case of arrays, so I respectfully disagree. Incidentally, the answer to this question is forthcoming.

Comment: But the question itself has code on dealing with arrays, and there's an array in the example data. He extracts the elements using a loop.

Comment: oh, I see what you mean. The question as asked contains the answer to my question. I feel that this isn't obvious, though. Intuitively, it would make sense to me that arrays of primitives would be parsed directly.

A concise answer to my question would read something like "each element in a primitive type array is a special case of a child node"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

JSON support, is spotty with boost property tree.

> The property tree dataset is not typed, and does not support arrays as such. Thus, the following JSON / property tree mapping is used:
>
> - JSON objects are mapped to nodes. Each property is a child node.
> - JSON arrays are mapped to nodes. Each element is a child node with an empty name. If a node has both named and unnamed child nodes, it cannot be mapped to a JSON representation.
> - JSON values are mapped to nodes containing the value. However, all type information is lost; numbers, as well as the literals "null", "true" and "false" are simply mapped to their string form.
> - Property tree nodes containing both child nodes and data cannot be mapped.

(from the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser))

You can iterate the array with a helper function.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> as_vector(ptree const& pt, ptree::key_type const& key)
{
    std::vector<T> r;
    for (auto& item : pt.get_child(key))
        r.push_back(item.second.get_value<T>());
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("{\"a\": [8, 6, 2], \"b\": [2, 2, 1]}");

    ptree pt;
    read_json(ss, pt);

    for (auto i : as_vector<int>(pt, "a")) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (auto i : as_vector<int>(pt, "b")) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/566631a144f8c5ff)**. Output:

```
8 6 2 
2 2 1
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Could anyone give the example code using boost_foreach? - I'm not able to use C++11 in my project.

Answer (score 16):

Read your `a` list as follows:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("a.")) {
    cout << v.second.data() << endl;
}
```

Comment: That's elegant with the trailing `.` in the path. +1 from me