# using boost for reading complex JSON arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, json, boost

related to [Using boost property tree to read int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481262/using-boost-property-tree-to-read-int-array)

I want to use boost (1.53.0) to read this:

```
{
  "model_json_version": "333",
  "model_actions": [
    {
      "action_type": "rep_processor",
      "rp_type": "basic_cln"
    },
    {
      "action_type": "feat_generator",
      "tags": "numeric"
    }
  ]
}
```

but the properties of the objects inside the array `model_actions` won't get printed!

my code:

```
for (ptree::value_type &p : pt)
    MLOG("1. [%s][%s]\n", p.first.c_str(), p.second.data().c_str());
for (ptree::value_type &p : pt.get_child("model_actions")) {
    auto& action = p.second;
    MLOG("\taction_type [%s]\n", action.get<string>("action_type").c_str());
    for (ptree::value_type &attr : action)
        MLOG("\t2. [%s][%s]\n", p.first.c_str(), p.second.data().c_str());
}
```

the printout:

```
1. [model_json_version][333]
1. [model_actions][]
    action_type [rep_processor]
    2. [][]
    2. [][]
    action_type [feat_generator]
    2. [][]
    2. [][]
```

why? what's wrong with the printout `2.`? why is it different from the printout at `1.`?

Comment: can you clarify what's the wanted result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON arrays are parsed into 'unnamed' subtrees; hence this

```
MLOG("\t2. [%s][%s]\n", p.first.c_str(), p.second.data().c_str());
```

will have empty strings as key and data; if you want its children, you should write:

```
MLOG("\t2. [%s][%s]\n", attr.first.c_str(), attr.second.data().c_str());
```

Comment: oops. brain-fart :( mindless copy-pasta and forgot to replace p with attr.